# What are [firebase-storage] and [google-cloud-storage] tags good for?

Tags: discussion, tags, collectives

Firebase essentially is part of [Google Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) (GCP) and its SDKs are a wrapper around some Google services. However, some features are exclusive to the Google side at the time of writing this, such as more runtimes like Java and Python while Firebase only supports [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).

My understanding so far has been that [firebase-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-storage) tagged questions mean the OP is using Firebase, i.e., can use security rules and [google-cloud-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage) means the question is more likely related some server side issue. This required no explicit confirmation from OP.

However, [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) is the only tag for Firestore and using it with either [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) or [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) tag made it clear if the OP is using Firebase Client SDKs or Firestore Server side SDKs. The question itself might give context about this but tags were good for categorization.

How do you differentiate/categorize such questions?

###### What level of specificity of tags is required in this case of the above similarities?

Should the [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) tag be included with every [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) question? Or when should we use the [google-cloud-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage) over [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) combination?

[firebase-realtime-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database) is not a GCP product directly to my knowledge, but should the GCP tag be added because Firebase is GCP product? [Questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database+google-cloud-platform)

And should questions like *[How to use a local SQLite database along with Firebase database and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273894/how-to-use-local-sqlite-database-along-with-firebase-database-android)*, where the root issue is not related to Google cloud computing in general, be tagged with [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) (only the data source is Firebase, but it is not the problem) have valid tags?

I am just seeking some clarification over the tags, so I do not categorize them incorrectly.

Comment: Side Note: The [[`firebase-storage`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firebase-storage/info)] Tag Excerpt sounds like complete Marketing "*look what for beautiful product we made that the world has been waiting for!*" Talk, ... and is indeed plagiarized from [this Presentation on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tyjqozrEPY)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existence of tag pairs such as [google-cloud-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage) and [firebase-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-storage) is indeed confusing, and mostly a historical artifact for products that existed inside of GCP before Firebase added direct client-side SDKs for them. Overall I find that I can get pretty far on just monitoring the `firebase-*` tags, and adding [google-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) and [google-cloud-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-functions).

From there on, I determine whether I can help with a question by looking for a product tag and a platform tag. So [google-cloud-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage)+[android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) for me is the same as [firebase-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-storage)+[android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), while [firebase-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-storage)+[go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) would be an unexpected combination (since there is no Go SDK from Firebase for Cloud Storage).

When you take it this way, the [google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) tag is mostly (harmless) noise, which is how I treat it. Everyone may have a different experience of course, in which case I'd love to see their answer on what tag combinations mean to them.

Comment: I agree on the _unexpected combination_ part (GCP can be used for web hosting but `[google-cloud-platform]` & `[android]`/`[ios]` does not seem to match). And with `firebase-authentication` getting more features from Identity Platform, having clear combination with either `firebase` or `gcp` makes it clearer if a solution with GCIP's feature would work for the OP or no imo (as not everyone might be willing to upgrade).